# Wrong initial routes after switching tabs inside drawer scenes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an error and I just don`t understand why it so...

I have the following navigation stack:

```
Drawer
  Tab0,
    Stack0(default)
      scene0(default)
      scene1
    Stack1
      scene2(default)
      scene3
  Tab1(default)
    Stack2(default)
      scene4
    Stack3
      scene4
```

So, my test path is:

```
Tab1.Stack2.scene4 ->
Tab0.Stack0.scene0 ->
Stack1.scene2 ->
Tab1.Stack2.scene4 ->
Tab0(.Stack0.scene0)
```

The last point in the parentheses because it expected point. But on this step the error happens:

`Error: There is no route defined for key 'Stack0'. Must be one of: 'scene2','scene3'`

I don`t know what should I post here for the trouble clarification, so feel free to tell me.

Comment: At the last step, are you navigating or resetting to scene0

Comment: @KranthiKumarJulakanti All the steps are made by UI methods (pressing on drawer menu and tabs)